# How to find (from a test script) a GET request executed form a JavaScript on a web-page?

Tags: javascript, python, rest, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm making some user tests using Selenium and python.
I have the following issue, which I'm trying to solve...:
The setup is the following:

- simple fron-end at http://localhost:**8080**/FE_page_1
- backend at http://localhost:**8888**/BE_project_v1.2

In the front-end there is a js which executes REST requests to the backend, when the page is loaded.

Is there a way with which I can find/see what is the url used in the in the REST request to the back-end from a selenium test/python script?

yes, I know the url! -> I don't want to be hardcoded in the test script!

I have tried requests, urllib and so on w/o success so far.
I can also see the REST request with all the data from the browser Dev-tools, but my goal is to make this automatic in the the test script itself.

Comment: You just open the network tab of dev tools to see those...

Comment: that's clear...but it's not the point of the question!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't tell what you're asking. This question doesn't really belong here, someone is going to come along and close it at some point